# Android: Right-Aligning ImageView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

The imageView is not getting right-aligned in this linearlayout (If it matters this LinearLayout is actually a row in a list).

But if i use a TextView (its commented in code below) instead of ImageView, it successfully gets right-aligned.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFAA"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<!--
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelNext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="> "
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
-->

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconNext"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" >
    </ImageView>     
</LinearLayout>
```

How do i get the imageView to the right-most edge of the LinearLayout row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` because `LinearLayout` does not support it. 
Use like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFAA" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconNext"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" >
    </ImageView>     
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add empty view between your imageView and textView that fill empty space between them and your second textview will be "pushed" to right side:

```
 <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Setting width to 0 and weight to 1 causes this view to fill whole available space, that is not used by other views. So it's size will be

> width = (screenWidth-(imageView width+textView width))

Comment: That might bring you troubles with different screen sizes, better use a frame layout in the parent view as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need a `TextView` with image on the right consider using a `android:drawableRight` parameter. Both `LinearLayout` with weights and `RelativeLayout` run measurement twice so leaving just `TextView` will be computationally faster.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow" />
```

*(Also please note that the arrow in `ListView` is against [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html))*