# Horizontal LinearLayout not showing any elements after nested Vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Following the Udacity Android for Beginners course, I want to add an audio icon button to a list_item view. Now the list_item.xml has a parent Horizontal Linear Layout and a nested Vertical Linear Layout. The course instructor added the audio icon by changing to a Relative Layout but i want to see how I could do this with a Linear Layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/tan_background"
              android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text=""/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text=""/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_play_arrow_white_24"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

My problem now is that when i add any element after the nested Vertical Linear Layout, nothing will show. I'm trying different things but I just can't understand. All i can think of is that this is the cause:

`android:layout_width:"match_parent"`

Please let me know how i can add the audio icon to the right and in the center while keeping this a LinearLayout.

This is the output i am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148631/android-right-aligning-imageview-in-linearlayout) Hopefully it helps otherwise :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/apptool"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:tint="@color/black"
        android:background="#ebed54"
        android:layout_weight=".1"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="sdfdsfdsf"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text="sdfdsfdsf"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: check my updated answer..let me if know if you have any issues

Comment: Yes, thank you! This works! I was nesting the layouts as well but i didn't think of creating another nested layout like this.

Answer (score 0):

You make width of linear layout match_parent so it consumes all remain place so you need to first change match_parent to wrap_content like below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/tan_background"
              android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_conten"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text=""/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            tools:text=""/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_play_arrow_white_24"/>


</LinearLayout>
```